# What would be the effects of a post-apocalyptic planet being almost completely consumed by darkness?

Tags: internal-consistency, post-apocalypse

One day, through means no one quite knows how, the world was consumed by near-total darkness. The sky became near pitch-black, the "days" only allowed little light through the clouds of darkness, and the nights became near impossible to see through. And then monster-like creatures started appearing in the darkness, hunting humans and taking over most of the world, though never trying to destroy existing structures/cities they encounter, except for small portions of humanity that have some-what functioning governments and homes to live in.

Given the context, what effects would a world being covered by near-total darkness have on the environment and the people/animals trying to survive in it?

Comment: One question per post, please.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I thought the follow-up questions would fall under the main one, as in the effects of a world being consumed by near-total darkness.

Comment: Everybody dies of starvation. Plants die first, herbivores die just a little later, then carnivores follow them. (That is, assuming that the *"clouds of darkness"* are local to the planet; if the darkness is induced by something blocking sunlight outside the atmosphere, then the planet quickly freezes over and everybody dies of hypothermia in a very short time.)

Comment: Since everybody will starve, what's the purpose of the monsters?

Comment: Well, I thought maybe there would be some way of people/animals adapting, but given the replies so far, I guess the only way the would happen is through, essentially, magic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Extinction of most creatures.**

Most food webs in our world are sustainained by photosynthetic organisms, *photo* being the key here. Without light, plants can't make photosynthesis, new organic matter can't be created and food chains will collapse, most likely resulting into the extinction of most species who rely, directly or indirectly, on plants, algae, phytoplankton and other producers which rely on light to survive, as well as most of these producers (except maybe those who require very little light, and that's an optimistic perspective). The only exceptions will be plants already cultivated without direct sunlight, but through the use of lamps,and whoever is allowed to eat them. Some abyssal species too will become extinct, safe for those part of food chains with other kinds of producers working as base. Those would likely take over the world, that is, the seas. The Land will have little life left, likely only whatever is still part of a working food chain and is capable of avoiding the new monstrous predators hunting them down.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate and direct effect would be cold.  Even solar eclipses produce a noticeable decline in temperature.  The eruption of Mount Tambora -- also known as Year Without a Summer and Eighteen Hundred and Froze To Death -- produced massive chilling, with snow in tropical eras, from a total of  0.4–0.7 degrees Celcius drop.  Yet that allowed in substantially more sunlight than you propose.  Cold sensitive animals and plants will start to die very quickly.

Quickly following on the cold will be the lack of sunlight killing all plants by destroying their ability to photosynthesize, and all animals for the lack of first plant, and then animal food.  It would be difficult to tease apart the effects after the first day or so, as the cold and the lack of photosynthesis would combine to kill faster than either could do alone.

Comment: [Anders Cel**s**ius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Celsius) with an **s** was a Swedish astronomer, physicist and mathematician. He lived in the first half of the 18th century.